# Removing un-named unique constraint

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using Alembic with Flask-SQLAlchemy, and I'm trying to remove a unique constraint on a column in one of my tables. Looking over the migrations - this constraint was never named: `sa.UniqueConstraint('title')`, obviously when I update the model, Alembic can't pick up that I removed `unique=True` off of it.

How do I create a migration that removes the constraint?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```py
with op.batch_alter_table('note', schema=None) as batch_op:
    batch_op.create_unique_constraint('title_uniq', 'title')
    batch_op.drop_constraint('title_uniq', type_='unique')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working was I had to have two migrations - one to create a named index and one to remove it.